# combine lines based on product id column in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to combine lines based on product id column in Excel using VBA into one row example below:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ ProjectCode ║ ProjectDescription ║ CUSTOMER Name ║ PRODUCT ID ║ PRODUCT DESCRIPTION ║ SUPPLIER Name ║ CUSTOMER ║ INVOICED QTY ║ Price Incl Vat  SUPPLIER ║ PURCHASED QTY ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1           ║ one                ║               ║ 123        ║ ONE TWO THREE       ║ SUPPLIER      ║          ║              ║ $51.12                   ║ 200           ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1           ║ one                ║ CUSTOMER      ║ 123        ║ ONE TWO THREE       ║               ║          ║ 170          ║ $51.12                   ║               ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1           ║ one                ║ CUSTOMER      ║ 123        ║ ONE TWO THREE       ║               ║          ║ 30           ║ $51.12                   ║               ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Desired Outcome:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ ProjectCode ║ ProjectDescription ║ CUSTOMER Name ║ PRODUCT ID ║ PRODUCT DESCRIPTION ║ SUPPLIER Name ║ CUSTOMER ║ INVOICED QTY ║ Price Incl Vat  SUPPLIER ║ PURCHASED QTY ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1           ║ one                ║ CUSTOMER      ║ 123        ║ ONE TWO THREE       ║ SUPPLIER      ║          ║ 200          ║ $51.12                   ║ 200           ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: What code are you using in your attempt?  Please paste it into the question because it will be almost impossible for us to just guess what you are doing.

Comment: im using vlookup but the problem is the data changes everytime for it is a extract from SQL database.

Comment: looking at it, it would be sumif(s), etc, cant this be done from the SQL Source though at the same time, would be a lot quicker in the long run...

Comment: If this is an export from an SQL db. Export it in the desired structure. Can you format your tables so it is clearer as to what you want?
[Table formatter](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.  It combines lines from "Sheet1" into "Sheet2" and assumes that your invoiced customer quantity is in Column "H".  Note that for a set of rows with identical ids the 1st row is copied over and only Column "H" is updated:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineLines()
  Dim wSht1 As Worksheet, wSht2 As Worksheet
  Set wSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set wSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

  Dim r As Integer: r = 2
  Dim rLast As Integer, rs As Integer, r2 As Integer: r2 = 2
  Dim tot As Double

  With wSht1
    .Rows(1).Copy
    wSht2.Rows(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

    rLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Do While r <= rLast
      If .Cells(r, "A") = .Cells(r + 1, "A") Then
        rs = r
        tot = 0#
        Do While .Cells(r, "A") = .Cells(r + 1, "A")
          tot = tot + .Cells(r, "H").Value
          r = r + 1
        Loop
        tot = tot + .Cells(r, "H").Value
      Else
        tot = .Cells(r, "H").Value
        rs = r
      End If
      .Rows(rs).Copy
      wSht2.Rows(r2).PasteSpecial
      wSht2.Cells(r2, "H").Value = tot
      r2 = r2 + 1
      r = r + 1
    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: yes that is perfect, i would like to understand which part of the code is carrying out for the following:  for a set of rows with identical ids the 1st row is copied over

Comment: The variable `rs` holds the row # for the 1st line which is copied over in the `.Rows(rs).Copy` line.